# Matplotlib development app problem in yticks()

Tags: matplotlib

i have this code in python, its not change coordinate y , plt.yticks  instruction not change, any help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1927, 1934, 1947, 1957, 1965, 1977, 1987, 1997]
population = [2968540, 3213174, 4816185, 6536109, 8261527, 12497000,16635199,19184543]

plt.plot(year,population,color="red")

plt.title("Iraq Population 1927-1997")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel("Population")


plt.yticks([0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20], ["0m", "4m", "8m", "12m", "16m", "20m"])

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have millions of people on the y-axis but want ticks at `0, 4, 8, 12, 16` and `20`.

I suggest to try

```
plt.yticks([0e6, 4e6, 8e6, 12e6, 16e6, 20e6], ["0m", "4m", "8m", "12m", "16m", "20m"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical usecase of a `matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter

year = [1927, 1934, 1947, 1957, 1965, 1977, 1987, 1997]
population = [2968540, 3213174, 4816185, 6536109, 8261527, 12497000,16635199,19184543]

plt.plot(year,population,color="red")

plt.title("Iraq Population 1927-1997")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel("Population")

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter())

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that EngFormatter uses a capital M for million, as this is the standard in the [SI system](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html).